# how to reject POST requests that are accessed from outside the server or from outside the website

Tags: php

Firstly, i am sorry if my english is not good.
I want to ask about how to reject POST requests that are accessed from outside the server or from outside the website.

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
//code
}

?>
```

Comment: This makes no sense. All requests will come from outside the server. Instead please tell us, what actual problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

this code will help you doing this :

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    function getIPAddress()
    {
        //whether ip is from the share internet  
        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
            $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        }
        //whether ip is from the proxy  
        elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
            $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        }
        //whether ip is from the remote address  
        else {
            $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        }
        return $ip;
    }
    $ip = getIPAddress();
    $request_addr = gethostbyaddr($ip);

    if ($request_addr == 'URL_i_want_to_reject.com') {
        return false;
        //Or die();
    } else {

        //// do some thing
    }
}
```

replace URL_i_want_to_reject.com to where you don't want to accept POST requests!

Answer (score 0):

In your script try to add an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

You can do something like that

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <your domain>');
```

Automatically if the client making the request is not from that origin, the request will be rejected.

Comment: This is only relevant to certain types of AJAX requests, and also usually more headers are required. Your answer should explain the context.